# Showing SQL results in a message box

Tags: c#, sql, messagebox

I am trying to show the results of a SQL query in a message box, but I'm having trouble getting this to work.

This is my code :

```
SqlConnection CN = new SqlConnection(constring);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
CN.Open();
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select  (Table_MAL_MEZANYAMASROF.MOKHASASMEZANYA- sum (MAL_ERTEBAT.MONY)) as 'debit' from Table_MAL_MEZANYAMASROF,MAL_ERTEBAT where Table_MAL_MEZANYAMASROF.BANDNO=MAL_ERTEBAT.BANDNO and  MAL_ERTEBAT.BANDNO= '" + EdkhalBayanto.txtBandNo.Text + "'and MAL_ERTEBAT.BANDNAME = '" + EdkhalBayanto.txtBandName.Text + "' group by Table_MAL_MEZANYAMASROF.MOKHASASMEZANYA", CN);
sda.Fill(dt);
MessageBox.Show(dt);
```

Comment: And exception or error message?

Comment: what you wanna show Here. `Datatable` ??

Comment: What if you get multiple results from this query? Would a MessageBox still be the right way to output these results to the user? Please consider this.

Comment: You can't show a DataTable in a MessageBox.   You could put the data in the MessageBox, but that could be quite a bit of work.

Comment: `dt` is not a string, it's a datatable. MessageBox is designed to take in strings. Also, you should use parameterized queries as you're vulnerable to SQL injections with that code.

Comment: want to show the result of select

Comment: if you want sql querry text, then this constructor initialises SelectCommand property of the SqlDataAdapter.

Comment: ok datatable is error here ,how to show sql query result on a message box

Comment: How many rows do you expect to come out of this query.. means will it be equal to one or more

Answer (score 2):

If you sure this query will return only one row in datatable with one column you can try this

```
MessageBox.Show(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only have one result, try this:

```
SqlConnection CN = new SqlConnection(constring); // declare connection as CN
string Query = "select  (Table_MAL_MEZANYAMASROF.MOKHASASMEZANYA- sum (MAL_ERTEBAT.MONY)) as 'debit' from Table_MAL_MEZANYAMASROF,MAL_ERTEBAT where Table_MAL_MEZANYAMASROF.BANDNO=MAL_ERTEBAT.BANDNO and  MAL_ERTEBAT.BANDNO = @BandNo and MAL_ERTEBAT.BANDNAME = @BandName group by Table_MAL_MEZANYAMASROF.MOKHASASMEZANYA" // declare query as string Query
CN.Open(); // open connection
using (var cmd = new SqlCeCommand(Query, CN)) // initialize a new SQL command
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@BandNo", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@BandName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);
    cmd.Parameters["BandNo"].Value = EdkhalBayanto.txtBandNo.Text;
    cmd.Parameters["BandName"].Value = EdkhalBayanto.txtBandName.Text;
    result = (string) cmd.ExecuteScalar(); // returns the first row of the first column, ignores everything else
}
CN.Close(); // close connection
MessageBox.Show(result); // show the result in a messagebox
```

Note how this uses parameters, instead of defining everything in the query itself. You might have to edit the parameters yourself.